# AJAX div not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax

Am working on a grails application. I need to retrieve database data using ajax. I'm having trouble replacing content, it's unnecessarily refreshing the header. My structure is:

```
<div id="header">
 <g:render template="/test/header"></g:render>
</div>
<div class="addrow">
 table content from db
</div>
```

My code is:

```
success: function(response){
 $(".addrow").html(response); 
}
```

It's refreshing the header also, not just the data. I tried with these also but no luck:

```
 $(".addrow").parent().html(response);
 $(".addrow").replaceWith(response);
```

Now do I avoid refreshing the header?

Comment: can you check with `$(".addrow").html($.parseHTML(response));`

Comment: @vijayP, nope same problem am getting

Comment: what you get in response

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder, yes am rendering template in this gsp page use i used g:render

Comment: @ Yo Yo, am getting proper output from server side problem in replacement, content is refreshing fine,but along that header also, how to avoid that

Comment: if content is refreshing fine ,, then how come its a replacement problem

Comment: along with table content header also refreshing

Comment: @naina: `$(".addrow").html(...)` with the structure you've shown **will not** replace anything in `<div id="header">..</div>` If you think it is, the code running is not quite what you think it is, or the structure isn't quite what you think it is. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/vd94zakz/

Comment: The fact that this is Grails is completely irrelevant and you should remove it from the question. Show the HTML **the browser sees**, not the Grails template; perhaps there's an error in the template which is causing what you're describing. (In fact, that's the only way I can see it happening, assuming everything currently in the question is accurate.)

Comment: if your ajax response isn't valid html your browser will try to amend it by doing changes in html structure (e.g. closing unclosed tags, etc), sometimes it does weird stuff.

Comment: @ derloopkat, yep once i ll check with those... thanq

Comment: Hi..Problem in response am getting complete page in response, how to get only particular div values i done using .find('div') but no use its take object value